# How do I override a parent class's method?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.io*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class StudentQueue<E> extends ArrayBlockingQueue<E>
{
    public StudentQueue(int capacity)
    {
        super(capacity);
    }
}
```

How do I override the corresponding parent class's methods?  I need to override methods in java library ArrayBlockingQueue.  How do I go about implementing my own method and having it override a method in parent class?

Any example will do, does not have to be ArrayBlockingQueue. Please and thank you.

Comment: The documentation covers class/method overriding, why don't you start there?

Comment: You've given no indication of what you've already tried. Every introductory text on Java will give an indication of how to override methods. Please indicate a *specific problem*.

Comment: Have you [looked at the tutorial?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. You _have to_ show the effort you've done so far, the _code_ you've written, and ask questions about specific problems you're having - you can't ask people to write the code for you

Comment: Check the lesson on the java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html Do your homework

Comment: By the way, when your previous question gets closed, that's an indication that something was wrong with it. The correct thing to do in this case is to learn from your mistake, figure out what's wrong with your post, and edit it to nominate it for reopening. Deleting your question and immediately re-asking it is not appropriate, and is why this question is already voted -5 and will likely be closed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method has the same name that the parent's, parameters and return type, you're overriding it. 
Also you can add `@Override` annotation on the top of your method.

Always check parent's method is not final nor private.

For instance

```
public class Parent{
  public void method(String param){
    //Do stuff
  }

  private void notExtendable(String param){

  }

  protected void alsoExtendable(String param){

  }
}

public class SubClass extends Parent{
  @Override
  public void method(String param){
    //super.method() //if you want to execute parent's method
    //Do your own stuff
  }
}
```

You have all information you need here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's say class `A` inherits from class `B`.  To have a method in `A` overwrite one of `B`'s methods, simply make a method with the same signature.  That is, make a method with the same return type, and the same number and type of parameters.

This is actually a very common thing to do.  For example, all classes should override the `boolean equals(Object o)` and `String toString()` methods from the `Object` class (which all classes inherit from).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did exactly that... just put your code below `super(capacity)`,